# Using xpath or ->nextSibling to read html file using curl

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Help please on how to extract data like 15,Teaching Periods 1 and 2.,Max 150. e.t.c from the sample html code below using DOMDocument function? I have tried to work around it but having mutiple tags before the text I like to extract makes it harder for me to extract all the content once as I have to save all the extracted data into mysql database.

```
<P><SPAN STYLE="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold"><a name="CS1050"class="modtitle">CS1050 Fundamentals of Internet Computing</a></SPAN></p>
<P><B>Credit Weighting: </B>15<BR><BR>
<B>Teaching Period(s): </B>Teaching Periods 1 and 2.<BR><BR>
<B>No. of Students: </B>Max 150.<BR><BR>
<B>Pre-requisite(s): </B>None<BR><BR>
<B>Co-requisite(s): </B>None<BR><BR>
<B>Teaching Methods: </B>72 x 1hr(s) Lectures; 18 x 2hr(s) Practicals.<BR><BR>
<B>Module Co-ordinator: </B>Professor Gregory Provan, Department of Computer Science.     <BR><BR>
<B>Lecturer(s): </B> Mr Gavin Russell, Department of Computer Science.<BR><BR>
<B>Module Objective: </B>To introduce students to Internet computer systems, web design, and<BR>client-side programming.<BR><BR>
<B>Module Content: </B>This module provides an introduction to the key concepts of Internet computing. Starting with the fundamentals of computer systems and the Internet, students progress to learn how to design web sites and how to utilize simple client-side programming. Issues related to user interface design and human-computer interfacing (HCI) are covered. Broader issues related to the use of the Internet for Blogging and Social Networks are discussed. The practical element of the module allows students to develop skills necessary for web site design using simple client side programming.<BR><BR>
<B>Learning Outcomes: </B>On successful completion of this module, students should be able to:<BR>&middot; Understand the fundamental principles of computer systems and the Internet;<BR>&middot; Design web sites;<BR>&middot; Use simple client-side programming;<BR>&middot; Understand the principles of user interface design and human-computer interfaces.<BR><BR>
<B>Assessment: </B>Total Marks 300: End of Year Written Examination 240 marks; Continuous Assessment 60 marks (Departmental Tests; Assignments).<BR><BR>
<B>Compulsory Elements: </B>End of Year Written Examination; Continuous Assessment.<BR<BR>
<B>Penalties (for late submission of Course/Project Work etc.): </B>Work which is submitted late shall be assigned a mark of zero (or a Fail Judgement in the case of Pass/Fail modules).<BR><BR>
<B>Pass Standard and any Special Requirements for Passing Module: </B>40%.<BR><BR>
<B>End of Year Written Examination Profile: </B>1 x 3 hr(s) paper(s).<BR><BR>
<B>Requirements for Supplemental Examination: </B>1 x 3 hr(s) paper(s) to be taken in Autumn. The mark for Continuous Assessment is carried forward.</P>



                   MY SAMPLE CURL CODE

$content3= $dom->getElementsByTagname('p');
$content4 = $dom->getElementsByTagname('b');

        //===========================================
        //=====  EXTRACT P STUFF ====================
        //===========================================

        foreach ($content3 as $value) {
            $contentnew[]= $value;
        print_r($value); 


        echo "Attribute Value = ";
        echo $value->getAttribute('value');
        echo "<br />";


        // let's get hold of the text value from the node
        $mytempvariable=$value->nodeValue;
        print "CONTENT OF P NODE: \n\n$mytempvariable <br /> <br />\n\n\n";
        }
        echo "<br /> <br /> <br />";



        //===========================================
        //===== EXTRACT B STUFF =====================
        //===========================================
        foreach ($content4 as $value) {
            $contentnew[]= $value;


        echo "Attribute Value = ";
        echo $value->getAttribute('value');
        echo "<br />";

        print_r($value); 
        // let's get hold of the text value from the node
        $mytempvariable=$value->nodeValue;
        print "CONTENT OF B NODE: \n\n$mytempvariable <br /> <br />\n\n\n";
        }
        echo "<br /> <br /> <br />";
```

I heard I could use ->nextSibling or xpath to extract all the data after all the b nodes but I cant seems to get around using xpath to extract all the relevant data I need.I could I do this please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close:

```
$result = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('b') as $node){
    $result[preg_replace('/:\s+$/','',$node->textContent)] = trim($node->nextSibling->textContent);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for that.It works great.Can you please explain how it work so I could understand this for some other time. Specially the regular expression please?

Comment: Well, `->nextSibling` is just the next sibling node in the tree (i.e: in the case the text directly after `</B>`), the regex is just to trim of the `: ` part in for instance `Credit Weighting: ` because I didn't like them in my case.... `textContent` is as stated a text-representation of the content of a node, without any tags.